# How can I split a long string into characters so that it matches with a given rectangle?

Tags: c#, xna

I have a rectangle and a string and sometimes the string is too long for the rectangle, then I just want to draw the characters of the string that are in the rectangle. Every character that exceeds the border of the rectangle should not be drawn. But I don't know how to split up the long string into characters.

I want to do almost the same thing as described in this question: [How can I split a long string so that it matches with a given rectangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57715767/how-can-i-split-a-long-string-so-that-it-matches-with-a-given-rectangle)

But this time, the result should look like this:

```
string Playernickname = "Best_playerrrindaworrrrrld!!!";

//if the string is too long, then just draw the part that is in the rectangle, for example:
Playernickname = "Best_playerrrindaworrr";

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{                
    graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.CornflowerBlue);
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.DrawString(Font, Playernickname, new Vector2(200, 300), Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
    spriteBatch.End();

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

How can I split up a string into characters and only drawing the part of the string that is in the given rectangle?

**UPDATE:**
I found out how to split a string into characters:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9b4e50dd-1136-42c8-af61-bbab96c5795d/split-a-word-to-characters?forum=csharplanguage

My code:

```
    string Playernickname = "Best_playerrrindaworrrrrld!!!";
    string[] Newword;
    Newword = Splitchar(Playernickname, 200, Font).ToArray();
    public static IEnumerable<string> Splitchar(string text, double rectangleWidth, SpriteFont font)
    {
        char[] chars = Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text));
        string buffer = string.Empty;

        foreach (var character in chars)
        {
            var newBuffer = buffer + character.ToString();
            if (character == chars[0])
                newBuffer = character.ToString();
            else
                newBuffer = buffer + character.ToString();

            Vector2 FontMeasurements = font.MeasureString(newBuffer);

            if (FontMeasurements.X >= rectangleWidth)
            {
                yield return buffer;
                buffer = character.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                buffer = newBuffer;
            }
        }
        yield return buffer;
    }

    //Drawing:
    //This only draws the characters of the string that are in the rectangle.
    spriteBatch.DrawString(Font, Newword[0], new Vector2(200, 300), Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
```

Comment: You are looking for Word Wrapping. See: [How do I implement word wrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986473/how-do-i-implement-word-wrap). You can easily adapt the code to have only the first line returned.

Comment: Is it possible to disassemble/split the string Playernickname into an array of characters? I want to find out how many characters of the string I can draw before the string exceeds the border of the rectangle. The string Playernickname only has one word("Best_playerrrindaworrrrrld!!!"), there are no other words in this string. I think word wrapping will not work in my situation because I don't want to split a text into words, I want to split a word/string into its characters. I can just draw the part of the string that is in the rectangle.

Comment: I found out how to split a string into characters.

Comment: If you've found the solution, you can post that as an own answer too and accept it yourself, that way it's more clear for us to see there's a solution found. :)